# One word describing a status that is either unstarted, started or completed

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that symbolize a status of either unstarted, started or completed ?

For example a football match can be either unstarted, started or completed.

I would like another word than "status" to indicate those lifecycle adjective, as we have a lot of other "status" in this context.

Something like "completionStatus" : but this is not really it, as this is just about completion. I thought about lifecycle but that's too biology oriented.

Comment: How about **Progress**?

Comment: [[A]] **matchStatus** ::= "unstarted | started | on-going | half-time | completed | abandoned | rescheduled | cancelled" [[B]] State [[C]] currentState [[D]] **gameStatus** [[E]] currentGameStatus

Comment: **Readiness state** is quite synonym of "completion status".

Comment: Names for use in computer programs are usually off-topic here, but "state" would be the usual choice.

Comment: This seems maybe a bit off-topic as it is about naming. But regardless, I don't see a problem with life-cycle: it's common to talk about things like a project life-cycle or product life-cycle. Unless there is a specific reason for not using terminology that relates to biology or life (maybe the OP works at a mortuary, IDK.)

Comment: @alphabet I didn't know. You might want to close this question then. I feel like progress is the best one for my taste here.

Comment: *timeline*.....

Comment: Not in this timeline , @TinfoilHat , We want a Point in the timeline.

Comment: When you say that you have a lot of other "Status" & hence you do not want to use it , the same is applicable to "Progress" , where you might have a lot of other Progress. Disambiguation is necessary , like in my Earlier Comment : matchProgress , gameProgress : In case , it is not about matches , you should use the suitable noun "X" to get XState , XStatus , XProgress , XCompletionStatus , ETC

Comment: Can you say what '… we have a lot of other "status" ' means, in any context?

What would be wrong with 'status' itself, since you're generally correct in seeing a football match as 'unstarted, started or completed' - though a choice from three options shouldn't be 'either' and you would be hard to find anyone using 'unstarted'. 

Might the reason 'completionStatus' won't serve be that 'completion…' adds nothing to 'Status' in English or your coding language?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin what do you mean by "you'd be hard to find anyone using unstarted" ? I feel like this is a pretty common word but this isn't my native language. Maybe not started is more common in oral speech though, but in written form, I'm pretty sure I've seen it.

Comment: @Ced Sorry, even though I left out the 'put', still it would be hard to find anyone using 'unstarted'. It does exist as a word yet verbally or on paper, it would be rare to find a native referring to a game as 'unstarted' rather than 'not started.' Search engines might give examples like 'We need to focus on the unstarted tasks' and I suggest that's wholly dependent on what went before and quite incapable of standing by itself.